# The Haskell function `openBrowser` opens Gimp and not my browser. However a Nautilus couble click opens the browser

Tags: haskell, mime-types

I modified the first example in https://hackage.haskell.org/package/svg-builder with the following 2 little changes:

1. Additional imports:

```
import Data.Text
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as TLIO
import Web.Browser(openBrowser)
```

2. New `main` program that writes the svg data to a file and then opens the browser with this file:

```
main = do
  TLIO.writeFile "test.svg" $ renderText $ svg contents
  openBrowser "test.svg" >>= print
```

The `openBrowser` comes from https://hackage.haskell.org/package/open-browser

When I run this program, my Debian (11.6) opens the `Gimp` program and not the browser.
When I double click on the written file in Nautilus, then the browser opens.

Where and what do I have to tweak, so that the Haskell program also opens the browser?

Answer (score 3):

Looking [at the code](https://github.com/rightfold/open-browser/blob/master/lib/Web/Browser/Linux.hs#L10) for the Browser library you're using, (at the time of writing):

```hs
openBrowserLinux :: String -> IO Bool
openBrowserLinux url = exitCodeToBool `fmap` rawSystem executable argv
    where (executable, argv) = ("sh", ["-c", "xdg-open \"$0\" 2>&1 > /dev/null", url])
          exitCodeToBool ExitSuccess     = True
          exitCodeToBool (ExitFailure _) = False
```

It is calling out to `xdg-open` which according to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open) for `xdg-open`:

> xdg-open opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application. If a URL is provided the URL will be opened in the user's preferred web browser. If a file is provided the file will be opened in the preferred application for files of that type. xdg-open supports file, ftp, http and https URLs.

To get this working on your system, you'll need to update the default program that handles `svg` files to be your preferred browser.

---

Getting this working in general is probably a larger task since the issue seems to be with the implementation in the library itself. You might want to bring it up with the library's maintainers or consider looking for another library.

Comment: With that in mind though, you might try adding `file://` to the beginning of the file location and see if `xdg-open` handles that differently

Comment: That's a bit annoying. It seems that `xdg-open` isn't really appropriate for a command called `openBrowser`. A better choice would be `sensible-browser`. That seems to be less standardized though.

Comment: @Souperman Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately prepending `file://` doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

After reading about the [xdg-mime command](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/xdg-utils/#xdg-mime) I did:

```
xdg-mime default firefox-esr.desktop image/svg+xml
```

and this solves the issue for the moment.

Comment: I think you mean `xdg-mime default firefox-esr.desktop image/svg+xml`.  Additionally, others may (like me) need to replace `firefox-esr.desktop` with just `firefox.desktop`.